# how to run Pycharm in debug mode on a multi-part command-line statement

Tags: python, windows, pycharm

*The title may be confusing so if you think of a better one, change it or tell me and I'll change it.*

Let's say you have this command:

```
cat f1.txt f2.txt | python script.py cmd1 | ... | python script.py cmd2 | ...
```

How can I launch the Pycharm debugger and single-step through the code of `script.py`?

This is on windows.

Comment: I have added an answer which might give you what you are looking for. But I strongly urge, you should have sample inputs and debug with them.

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm has the feature to run tasks via *Run/Debug configurations*. I will try to emulate your requirement with them here. Adapt it according to your needs.

1. Choose `Edit Configurations`:

[image: Edit Configuration in Run/Debug Menu]

2. Click the Add button <kbd>+</kbd> and choose `Bash`

[image: Run/Debug Dialog - Add configuration]

3. Input the bash script that you wish to run with `/bin/bash`.  If it is a single command then, my workaround is to put the first argument in the script name's place and the second argument onwards at the `Program Argument` space.

[image: Input for running cat as a bash config]

4. Switch to `Python` > `your_script` in the left tab and add the now created task in the `Before launch: Activate tool window`. Click <kbd>+</kbd> > `Run Another Configuration`, select the bash config added in the previous step. It should look something like the one below:

[image: Adding another configuration before python]

5. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> and close the `Run/Debug Configuration` window.
6. Set breakpoints, select the config that you want to debug and click the Debug button.

[image: Debugging the script]

7. Repeat the steps 2 to 4 as many times to add your multiple commands.

I haven't really tried to do this for a complex multi command operation. I usually break it down and debug the script separately. You can consider saving the output to files and using them.

**Caveat:**

From your example command it looks like you are piping the output of one command to another, I haven NOT yet figured out a way to forward the output of one configuration into another.

**Possible Workarounds:**

1. If they are all Python scripts, then you could try to save each output to file using the option from `Logs` tab.

[image: Saving the output of python script using Logs options]

2. Sadly `Bash Configuration` doesn't have a save output feature. The work around could be to write a bash file that saves the output to a file and run that bash script in the `Bash Configuration`.

[image: bash script saving output]

```
# contents of cat_files.sh
cat file1.txt file2.txt > outfile.txt
```

Now in the python script config you could pass in `outfile.txt` as a parameter and read it to get the data.