# PyCharm Tests Add Shell Command to Additional Arguments

Tags: junit, pycharm, pytest

I'm still pretty new to running anything in PyCharm more advanced than just a simple script. I'm writing a test in pytest right now and I want to have the test results output to a junit xml file; I'm thinking the best naming convention will be based on the current date/time, so I am trying to pipe in the current date using the date shell command as an environment variable as seen below:

[Current Configuration:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHj65.png)

However, when I run the configuration as-is, it just names the .xml file based on the command without actually executing it. Any ideas what I'm missing, or if this is even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, it is possible with a workaround**. I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible using a single configuration. The the value you set in Environment variables are substituted as-is and wouldn't be executed in bash prior to that.

The workaround would be use multiple configurations.

1. Store the following line in a bash file.

   `export PYTEST_EXEC_TIME=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S')`
2. Add a bash configuration to which executes this file.
3. Add that configuration to the pytest configuration as a "Before Launch" configuration and use the `$PYTEST_EXEC_TIME` in the additional parameters.

**Note:** [Here is a detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46732437/how-to-run-pycharm-in-debug-mode-on-a-multi-part-command-line-statement) showing step by step process of setting up a "Before Launch" configuration.